# Get value of array stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, api, object, stdclass

I am performing an insertion of values ​​using an api.
then, I send the values ​​correctly and get the return on the same page.
Eg:

```
<?php
...
$return= $set->createCharge([
   'description'    => 'Strings etc...',
   'amount'     => 10.0
)];

print_r($return);
```

?>

**This print_r Result is:**

```
stdClass Object
(
[data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [charges] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [code] => 555
                        [reference] => 66
                        [dueDate] => 23/11/2020
                        [checkoutUrl] => https://url/number_return
                        [link] => https://url_return
                        [installmentLink] => https://url
                        [payNumber] => 9999999999
                        [billetDetails] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [bankAccount] => 888888
                                [ourNumber] => 12121-9
                                [barcodeNumber] => 0541454141411141414141414
                                [portfolio] => 0001
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[success] => 1
```

)

I tried to get the value '[code']
using the following:

```
echo $return[0]['code'];//Dont work

echo $return['data']['charges'][0]['code'];//Dont Work
```

how can I get the value of [code] or another that is in that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element in the "charges" array is an object. A different syntax is used to refer to the members of the object:

```
//for an array
echo $someArray['someValue'];

//for an object
echo $someObject->someValue;
echo $someObject->getSomeValue()
```

Therefore, this is the way for you:

```
echo $return->data->charges[0]->code;
```

Or, step by step:

```
var_dump($return);
var_dump($return->data);
var_dump($return->data->charges);
var_dump($return->data->charges[0]);
var_dump($return->data->charges[0]->code);
var_dump($return->data->charges[0]->code->billetDetails);
var_dump($return->data->charges[0]->code->billetDetails->bankAccount);
```

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500
In Apache error log say : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: I updated my answer. Try the code from the last paragraph ("Or, step by step").

Comment: Yep. Its work! 
var_dump($return->data->charges[0]->code);
This result -> path_url/code.php:34:int 136023929
Running echo  $return->data->charges[0]->code;
Output: 136023929
Thanks man.